# python random choices generate same result instead of random

Tags: python-3.x

I expect some 1s and 0s printed each iteration but they's all either 0s or 1s. so the `random.choices` seems not random and I don't see the probability distribution. any idea?

```
import random
a = random.choices(population=[['a','b'], ['b','a'], ['c','b']], weights=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6],k=6)
for i in range(10):
    print(a)
```

output: (sometime all 1s)

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

Comment: Yep. You pick a single random item and then print it ten times.

Comment: just interchange the position of `a` and `for loop` the solution will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is settings `a` once at the start, and then printing it 10 times.

The `a =` line needs to be inside the for-loop.

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    a = random.choices(population=[['a','b'], ['b','a'], ['c','b']], 
                       weights=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
                       k=6)
    print(a)
```